# Cypress: Using multiple selector wih OR condition

Tags: javascript, html, testing, automated-tests, cypress

I have multiple login pages as:

#### First login page

Input element is as:

```html
<input placeholder="name@email.com" class="input" name="email" type="text" value="">
```

Cypress selector is as follows:

```js
cy.get('input[name="email"]').as('email').click();
```

#### Second login page:

Input element is as:

```html
<input id="email" type="email" required="required" class="input">
```

Cypress selector is as follows:

```js
cy.get('input[id="email"]').as('email').click();
```

If we notice, the 1st input element has `name=email` while the 2nd has `id=email`.
Is there a way to write a cypress selector where it can look for selector `input[name="email"]` if not found it looks for `input[id="email"]`?

Comment: @Awaji-mitop N. Gilbert's answer will work, but I want to ask why you are pursuing conditional testing for this scenario? This doesn't feel like a situation where you would need to conditionally check for an ID, but instead could definitely check for the id or name, and would have definite control over which page you are on.

Comment: Hi @agoff, If I understand you, then yes, we can have 2 different tests for the two pages separately. Also, depending on the use case, the login forms can be uniquely identified and as such, we can definitely test knowing when to query element based on id or name. However, the overall code structure is not known so I believe a straightforward answer to do this would be to check if the query finds an item and then perform actions on the item. Basically, a rearrangement of the code would be better and there would be no need for conditional testing but that again depends on the bigger picture.

Comment: @Awaji-mitopN.Gilbert Yep! Exactly what I'm saying -- your answer is completely fine, I just want to challenge OP on why they are writing a conditional test to begin with.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is. It is called cypress conditional testing according to the [docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/conditional-testing#Element-existence).

There are a number of ways to get this done as seen in the docs depending on what you may want.

Below is something we can do

```
  cy.get('input[name="email"]').then(($btn) => {
    if ($btn.length) {
      // do something if it's active
      $btn[0].click();
    } else {
      // do something else
      cy.get('input[id="email"]').as('email').click();
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the comma `,` to do an OR condition if you are using css selectors. Something like:

```js
cy.get('input[name="email"],input[id="email"]').click()
```